# how to programmatically check protection on a word document vbscript

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, ms-office, word-2010

I'm using a vbscript to programmatically run through a list of word documents, open each one, modify it, then save it using ms word 2010. My problem is there are protected and unprotected documents in the list.  When I reach a protected document, I get this error: This method or property is not available because the object refers to a protected area of the document.

So I did some research and found this code on the ms website:

```
If objDoc.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
                objDoc.Unprotect
End if
```

Now the problem is a new error: The unprotect method or property is not available because the document is already unprotected. Is there a another way to check if the document is protected or unprotected, when you know there will be both in the list, to avoid the errors?

Comment: Did you define wdNoProtection? (Like "Const wdNoProtection = <Correct value obtained from Docs/Debug output>)

Comment: No, I'm a java developer that is trying to get some tasks done in vbscript.  I'll try that.

Comment: Well that worked! I didn't set the inital value of the property. If you put your answer down I'll mark it answered. Thanks, James

Comment: it's a good idea to pop `option explicit` at the top of your script so any error caused by undefined variables are caught

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you automate MS Office applications using VBScript (and use VBA sample code as a starting point), you may overlook the necessity of defining the wd*, xl*, or ad(?)* constants that are predefined in VBA, but missing in VBScript. Use the Docs and/or Debug output to add lines like:

```
Const wdNoProtection = <correct value>
```

to your script.

If you start your script with `Option Explicit` and either avoid the evil global `On Error Resume Next` entirely or at least disable it until the program is tested, you won't miss any of these beasts.

An even better approach is to write your script as a .wsf file. The `<reference>` tag 'includes' the definitions (so you can't be blamed for an incorrect Const line).

POC/Demo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<package>
 <job id="QEC">
  <reference object="Excel.Sheet" reference="true"/>
  <script language="VBScript">
   <![CDATA[
' ############################################################################
  a = inputbox ( "Name of an Excel Constant?" )
  msgbox a & " = " & eval(a)
' ############################################################################
   ]]>
  </script>
 </job>
</package>
```